# Passing java.lang.Object as Web service parameter - null result on the client

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I know a similiar question has been asked already but there is a small difference between my question and the one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541641/using-java-lang-object-as-web-service-parameter

I use apache cxf 2.7.5 with jaxb databinding, java 1.7.

When I send a request through SOAP UI the client gets null value. 
Object unmarshalled as org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.

Is it possible to get a not null java.lang.Object unmarshalled?

Thanks in advance, emph

Comment: just out of curiosity, how would you use the object after it is unmarshalled ?

Comment: I would then cast the Object to a certain type, based on properties which I have passed in a soap request

Comment: i thought so, now imagine if you dont have any relevant properties in soap request to determine which type should object belong/cast to, what would you do ?

Comment: i would raise an exception :-) I'm trying to implement an Adapter to do what i want.

Comment: i was making a point, if cxf doesn't know what type should be used, it uses its default class.

Comment: yes, i understand and see it in debug. but I would really expect an exception there so i know directly without even debugging it.

Comment: maybe you should give your own provider to cxf for mapping and then you can raise an exception in that case